# Emulator and Device give different results

Tags: android, time, android-emulator, device, simpledateformat

I have been working on an application that **calculates** time difference and have this really wierd problem, the **emulator** and **device** give different results.

If the time is set **22:00** to **22:45** on the emaulator the difference is **45**.
When I do the same thing when I run on the **device** I get **15**

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is code how I calculate the hours/min

```
public int theTimeMachineHours(EditText a, EditText b) throws Exception{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(a.getText().toString());
    Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(b.getText().toString());

    long difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    if(difference<0)
    {
        Date dateMax = simpleDateFormat.parse("24:00");
        Date dateMin = simpleDateFormat.parse("00:00");
        difference=(dateMax.getTime() -startDate.getTime() )+(endDate.getTime()-dateMin.getTime());
    }
    int days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));
    int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60));
    int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);

    return hours;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is code from one part in the code where the timeMachine method is called:

```
if(restFrom2Day1.length()!=0){
        sendBreakHour2Day1 = ""+theTimeMachineHours(restFrom2Day1,restTo2Day1);
        sendBreakMin2Day1 = ""+theTimeMachineMin(restFrom2Day1,restTo2Day1);
        hour2Day1 = Integer.parseInt(sendBreakHour2Day1);
        minute2Day1 = Integer.parseInt(sendBreakMin2Day1);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code to determine the time difference?

Comment: @babadaba I have added code now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are under DST zone (Daylight Saving Time), right?

This way, your device is may marking 23:00 (and not 22:00).

Maybe, you are setting the calendar to 22:00. However, since DST is active, your time is in fact 23:00 (22:00 + DST enabled flag). So, maybe, that's why you are getting 15 and not 45 minutes.

Comment: Ok. How do I disable this.

Comment: Share more code in your question.. just to see how you are setting the time/calendar etc...

Answer (score 0):

Does this produce other results for you?

```
public long theTimeMachineHours(EditText a, EditText b) throws Exception{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(a.getText().toString());
    Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(b.getText().toString());


    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    long minutesInMilli = 1000 * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;

    long hours = different % (hoursInMilli * 24) / hoursInMilli;
    long minutes = different % hoursInMilli / minutesInMilli;

    return hours;
}
```

Comment: You can cast the hours to int if needed

Comment: What are you typing in your EditTexts?

Comment: I am setting the time from a TimePicker

Comment: But a timepicker doesn't work with EditTexts as far as I know. Can you provide the code where you call the theTimeMachineHours method?

Comment: Check the update. Timepicker is working fine. What about DST

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe try simpleDateFormat .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); change GMT with your timezone